# Opacity transition causing animation interruption

Tags: css, animation

I have a list of elements, which when hovered over show a set of controls to remove them. The controls transition in with opacity values.

```
.duplicate-controls {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity linear 0.7s; }

.duplicate-group:hover .duplicate-controls {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity linear 0.7s; }
```

When I'm animating the content, it'll skip or interrupt the animation in a jarring fashion. If I remove the opacity transitions, i can't reproduce the issue.

Please see the following gif for a visual representation of what i'm talking about.

This is it interrupting.
http://gfycat.com/IncomparableBlaringAsianporcupine

This is how it should animate.
http://gfycat.com/CheapMajesticBluebottlejellyfish

Comment: try removing the 2nd transition or the 1st one, see if it works..

Comment: Only seems to work if I have none of the transitions.

Comment: you should use `transition: opacity 0.7s linear` _instead of_ `transition: opacity linear 0.7s`, after `linear` **0.7s** specifies delay time and not duration time, use this in combination by removing the 1st or 2nd `transition` property.

Comment: I've done that, and it's still resulting in the same issue. Good to know though about the order of those parameters.

Comment: then you should create a jsfiddle of all the codes in which the problem is persisting with mock data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the transition property from

```
.duplicate-group:hover .duplicate-controls{}
```

Comment: That seems to make it happen more frequently, and it's still happening.

Comment: Can you post a link to your site. Or can you provide HTML/CSS related to it.

Comment: I have updated the gifs. should be a little more understandable what i'm trying to achieve. I'll see if I can find time a little later to post it, since right now it has confidential information. I'll try to replace all of the confidential info with junk data.

Comment: Please try here. http://cowlephant.com/testing/   note I hamfisted find and replace on the data, so a lot of things aren't as they're intended, but it at least shows the issue. Don't laugh at my files, especially css... i'm a css rookie!